# Custom keyboard layout: Command+V doesn't paste in Safari and Mail

Tags: keyboard, safari, shortcut, keybindings

I have created a custom keyboard layout (`.keylayout` file) and remapped (amongst other keys) the `X`, `C` and `V` keys. However, I want to keep **Cmd+X/C/V like on the QWERTY**, because it's practical and I am used to it.

So in my layout, I have kept the original `X, C, V` mappings for when <kbd>Command</kbd> is pressed:

```
<keyMap index="0">  <!-- No modifiers -->
  ...
  <key code="7" action="y" /> <!-- my modified layout -->
  <key code="8" action="x" />
  <key code="9" action="." />
...
<keyMap index="10">  <!-- command -->
  ...
  <key code="7" output="x" /> <!-- same as qwerty -->
  <key code="8" output="c" />
  <key code="9" output="v" />
```

This works well *except for <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (which should do a <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, i.e. paste) in Safari, Mail and a few other Apple applications…* In that case, using the original <kbd>V</kbd> key (on a QWERTY keyboard) does work…

I don't understand why it fails just for this shortcut? I've read that some `Cmd+…` shortcuts are special and can't be overridden, but why does it work with cut/copy but not with paste? And why does it work in all applications except Safari and Mail?

---

I've used the [bepo](http://bepo.fr/wiki/Accueil) (french dvorak) layout and edited it in a text editor. My version [is on GitHub](https://github.com/mnapoli/bepo/blob/master/results/final/macosx/layout-matthieu.keylayout). I have opened my layout in Ukulele and it shows it quite fine, is there anything I could try with it to debug/detect problems?

I have also tried to open+save my layout with Ukulele and it doesn't work anymore, it's not even detected by OS X. I have reverted back to my version.

Comment: Did you use Ukelele to make your custom layout?

Comment: No I used the [bepo](http://bepo.fr/wiki/Accueil) (french dvorak) layout and edited it in a text editor. My version [is on github](https://github.com/mnapoli/bepo/blob/master/results/final/macosx/layout-matthieu.keylayout). I have opened my layout in Ukulele and it shows it quite fine, is there anything I could try with it to debug/detect problems?

Comment: You might try saving it in Ukelele to see if it makes any difference.  Also there is a Ukelele mailing list where someone might have an idea:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Comment: @TomGewecke I have tried to open+save my layout with Ukulele and it doesn't work anymore, it's not even detected by OS X. I have reverted back to my version. I'll ask on the mailing list thanks for the link.

Comment: The ukelele users group was unable to help?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that you're trying to use **Command** + **.** to mimic the behaviour of **Command** + **v** (i.e. for Paste)? And, are you saying this **does** work, but not for Apple software such as Safari, Mail, etc?

Comment: @Monomeeth yes exactly

Comment: @TomGewecke I didn't use Ukulele to write the layout (it's here https://github.com/mnapoli/bepo). I remember I did ask for help anyway but nobody was able to help unfortunately.

Comment: As I know with  the **Command + .**  on Safari you can cancel operations for example cancel Search queries and works like the ESC Command.

Comment: @dante12 good to know, that might be some sort of hardcoded shortcut that prevents my shortcut from happening.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Sorry, just saw your comment. I guess what I was getting at was whether this is (i) only happening with Apple software and, if so, (ii) happening with all Apple software. Basically the **Command** + **.** keyboard shortcut has been used by Mac OS for decades as a universal "halt operations" keyboard shortcut. I've just added an answer to provide you (and others) more details.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not surprised you may be experiencing this issue with Apple Software. Basically the <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> keyboard shortcut has been used by Mac OS for decades as a universal "halt operations" keyboard shortcut.

In a sense it works in a similar way to the ESC key. So I am thinking this is why you are experiencing problems with this keyboard shortcut. It used to be that software developers had to respect this <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> keyboard shortcut for any software they developed for the Mac platform, but this is no longer the case, hence why your keyboard shortcut may be working with some software but not others. You may want to read the [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html) page in the macOS Human Interface Guidelines.

**Extra Info**

Apple first introduced the Command key in 1980 with the Apple III computer.

The purpose of the Command key was to allow users to enter keyboard commands in applications and within the operating system. The Macintosh Human Interface Guidelines have always recommended that developers use the Command key (and **not** the Control or Option keys) for this purpose.

A small set of keyboard commands (such as cut and paste, open and save) are standard across all applications. If an application needs more shortcuts than can be obtained with the twenty-six letters of the English alphabet, double modifiers such as Command+Option are used.

The Macintosh keyboard's other unusual modifier key, the Option key, serves as a modifier both for entering keyboard shortcuts and for typing text — it is used to enter foreign characters, typographical symbols, and other special characters.

As mentioned previously, the <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> shortcut was once a universal recommended shortcut, but this is no longer reserved by macOS. In fact, [Table 67-3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH84-SW3) of the macOS Human Interface Guidelines now only lists one keyboard shortcut with a period (.) in it. This is the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> keyboard shortcut for increasing screen contrast. You can read more about this in [Accessibility Programming Guide for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078).

Comment: Oh wow thank you for getting to the bottom of this, it's been bugging me for maybe five years! Now with "what can I do" questions :) (1) Is there a chance that macOS Sierra or future macOS will fix it since this shortcut is no longer reserved? (2) Do you see anything that I can do?

Comment: These are only my first thoughts: (1) Yes, there is a chance that future Apple software / operating systems will no longer use the **Command** + **.** shortcut, especially as new software is developed - but the incentive to remove it from existing software may not be there as many long-term users (myself included) still default to using the **Command** + **.** shortcut to stop a process they've just started.

Comment: (2) The main thing you could do is change the shortcut, but I appreciate you won't want to do that. But you may already be used to using the CTRL key on Windows machines for cut/copy/paste etc, so maybe... :) You may also get some temporary relief from using a different browser, etc. (although I'm pretty sure that both Firefox and Chrome use the **Command** + **.** shortcut on Macs to stop a process. Another option may be to play with the various settings in the Keyboard pane of System preferences (but you've probably already tried this at some point and had no joy).

Comment: (2) I actually remapped Command and Control a long time ago (System Preferences) and always used it that way. TBH I never tried without the remapping to see if it would work. To be clear I'm pressing `Ctrl+v` and it translates to `Command+.` Also I'm using Chrome for this reason, and Airmail too. The apps where there's the problem are: Safari, Mail. The **Apple** apps where it works: Calendar, Notes, TextEdit, Pages, App Store, etc. That's why I find it so weird… Only Mail and Safari…

Comment: Oh and actually (I don't try that often since I tend to avoid those apps) pasting works everywhere in Mail **except** in a mail body (when writing a new email). In Safari it doesn't work in the address bar and in website forms (but works for example in preferences). I think it's something to do with application widgets or something…

Comment: In that case you'll probably find in time the **Command** + **.** shortcut will work in Safari and Mail, as it seems it's no longer a universal shortcut within those apps. You could provide feedback to Apple [here for Safari](http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html) and [here for Mail](http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html). Good luck!